# Where to find the tensorflow-serving URL?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, docker-compose, tensorflow-serving

I created a `Dockerfile` for `tensorflow-serving` as follows:

```
FROM tensorflow/serving

COPY /model_dir /models/model/
```

and I `docker-compose` it this way

```
  tensorflow-servings:
    container_name: tfserving_classifier
    build: ./some_model_dir
    ports:
      - 8501:8501
```

In the tensorflow-container, the model is located in `/models/model/1`

Here is how I tried to serve it

```
# server URL
url = 'http://localhost:8501/v1/models/model/1:predict'


def make_prediction(instances):
    data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": instances.tolist()})
    headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
    json_response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    predictions = json.loads(json_response.text)['predictions']
    return predictions
```

Here is the python code container message:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8501): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /v1/models/model/1:predict (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x7f315c19c4c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
> Connection refused'))

I believe this is due to incorrect URL, how can I get the correct URL for my tensorflow-serving?

Here is the tensorflow-serving container message:

```
I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:393] Running gRPC ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:8500 ...

I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:414] Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:8501 ...
```

Comment: is the python script running inside a container ?

Comment: @DefSoudani yes the python script is running inside a container, and the tensorflow-serving is running another container. Both are within the docker-compose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`localhost` only reaches inside the container, use service name or container name of tensorflow to reach it from the script container

`http://tensorflow-servings:8501/v1/models/model/1:predict`

Comment: you are a star! Thank you very much. The URL was ` 'http://tensorflow-servings:8501/v1/models/model:predict'`